# How to keep my ping/latency steady in cs 1.6?

Tags: ping, latency, broadband

I have broadband connection with 512 kbps speed. Sometimes I get 200 latency and sometimes 300. How can I keep that steady? It's really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Upgrade your internet and get higher speeds package and/or make sure you play on a server that is not overloaded and also geographically very close to your region. anything under 1 Megabits is usually so vulnerable to lag anyways.